# AbsoluteLayoutDemo.java in Oracle Java Tutorials

Tags: java, swing

**Question 1:**

I am writing a program to use an absolute layout because I need to reposition a `JLabel` at runtime. I have tried to understand the following java demo program (from Oracle Java Tutorials):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/AbsoluteLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/AbsoluteLayoutDemo.java

It suggests the following:

```
//Size and display the window.
Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
frame.setSize(300 + insets.left + insets.right, 125 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The frame is not set to be visible before the `insets` values are calculated, so they are all `0` (zero), am I getting it right?

I have tried to use `frame.setSize(300, 125);` to replace the code and Eclipse gives me the same result (the same window size as I have observed). Is it wrong to have `setSize` before `setVisible`?

**Question 2:**

In my own program, I have the following code segment:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel moving_label = new JLabel();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
panel.setLayout(null);
frame.add(panel);
panel.add(moving_label);
moving_label.setBounds(150, 150, 50, 50);
moving_label.setIcon(img);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300+frame.getInsets().left+frame.getInsets().right,
    300+frame.getInsets().top+frame.getInsets().bottom);
//I don't need to have panel.validate() or panel.repaint(), right?
```

a) Is the above code segment in a **correct order** (I am a newbie of java's Swing GUI)?

b) I am using Eclipse on my MacBook Pro to run Java programs. I have 40 `JLabel`s (each with an `ImageIcon`) in a `JPanel` in a `JFrame`. If I use the above codes to generate the GUI, it takes half a second to show all `JLabel`s after the window is displayed. Why aren't the JLabels shown at the same time the window is displayed?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

> The frame is not set to be visible before the insets values are calculated, so they are all 0 (zero), am I getting it right?

Correct, components do not have a size until the frame has been `realized`, which means the native objects on the OS you are running on have been created. This is done when you `pack()` the frame or make the frame visible.

If you are trying to make the panel that contains the label a size of (300, 125) then the easier approach would be to do:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(300, 125) );
panel.add(...);
frame.add( panel );
frame.pack();
//frame.setLocation(...);
//frame.setLocationByPlatform();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Now the pack() method will determine the size of the frame based on the preferred size of all the components added to the frame. No need to worry about insets.

Note: as a general rule you should not invoke setPreferredSize() on a component, since each component is responsible for determining its own size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution works as well and thanks to that I don't need to worry about insets anymore when I use `null` layout manager. But I have encountered the same issue which I pointed out in my question. There is a slight delay between the blank window's display time and the `JLabel`s' display time. Indeed, before using `null` layout manager, I have these: `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 5))`, `panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(x, y))`, `panel.add(...)`, `frame.add(panel)`, `frame.pack()` and `frame.setVisible(true)` which the window and `JLabel`s show up together.

Comment: If I change `setMinimumSize(...)` to `setPreferredSize(...)`, the slight delay is back, otherwise no delay. Do you have any idea for this performance issue (although it only happens in Eclipse for Mac)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't play with the sizes. Let the layout manager do its job. I don't know how you are loading your images. Maybe it takes time to load the images so the GUI is displayed before all the images are loaded.